# Equivalence of norms in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: normed-spaces

Does anyone know some proofs where we use fact of equivalence of norms(I think some
 L continuity use this fact). Any literature of  proofs would be very useful. Thank's a lot.

Comment: I don't know what book my professor got it from, if any, but most proofs on differentiability switched between various norms in manipulating limits. For instance, that the Jacobian Matrix is the differential (in canonical coordinates), $\mathcal C^1 \Rightarrow$ Differentiability,  and some other ones.

It's also useful as a topological fact in itself, as it allows one to speak of *the* normed space $\Bbb R$, without regards to whichever norm it may be. In an infinite dimensional space, say that of continuous functions, we don't have this benefit.

Comment: Thank you. Does something from diferential equation theory use this fact?? Do you know something about it??